# Resources (some css and js files) not loaded in Safari browser (iphone devices)

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, html, css

I am running into a very strange problem...
I made a website for the company I am working in (using HTML5, CSS 3, jQuery, PHP), the website now is in production, tested in all browsers (chrome, firefox, edge..etc) and devices (android and ios).
Before 2 days someone from the company tested the website with an iphone 8 (I tested it then also with iphone 7  and 6s), and the for the browser safari only the website can't be loaded (view screenshot).
[screenshot about how the website looks in safari in iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BYnB.jpg)
I tested the website in Safari browser on a Mac but works fine without any problem.
I saw other posts but no one could help in my problem.
All css and js files used are located in the same folder as the project (no call to external resource)
The iOS version is 12.1.4
The requests are sent with HTTP/1.1

Comment: Try using the iOS emulator in Safari on desktop. Then you can check the console to see any errors or missing references. As your question stands we can't help you as you've not shown us any code to reproduce the problem

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I tried to run the website on some simulators but the problem can't be reproduced...

Comment: HI Moses, if you any solution for this, can update here. I am also facing similar issue with iOS 9.3. On rest of ios versions it is working fine. Here i tried to debug this using browserstack but debugging tools were disabled for this.

Comment: Unfortunately I just gave up